# How to recover connection pool from "unknown database" error with node mysql2

Tags: mysql-connector, node-mysql2

I'm using the changeUser method in the mysql2 npm package to connect our API to different databases in our database instance:

```
const pool = createPool({
  namedPlaceholders: true,
  ...dbConfig,
});

async function getConnection(database) {
  const connection = await poolMain.getConnection();
  await connection.changeUser({ database });
  return connection;
}
```

When I pass an invalid database the connection fails as intended.

But after one failed attempt all following attempts of getConnection fail as well, even when a valid database is passed.

The only solution that I found was to recreate the pool in case of `err.code === "ER_BAD_DB_ERROR"`:

```
let pool = createPool({
  namedPlaceholders: true,
  ...dbConfig,
});

async function getConnection(database) {
  try {
    if (database === "betenergie_db") {
      return await poolBet.getConnection();
    } else {
      const connection = await pool.getConnection();
      connection.changeUser({ database });
      return connection;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code === "ER_BAD_DB_ERROR") {
      pool = createPool({
        namedPlaceholders: true,
        ...dbConfig,
      })
    }
    throw err;
  }
}
```

Is a more elegant way of recovering the pool without reinstantiating it?